# Angular 4 + Firebase Database + File Storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, firebase-storage

Lately I've been developing a app and I've found some difficulties when trying to assemble everything.
My idea was to have a place where I can submit data + images, this is where I came up with.

[image]

And this is the component.ts where I have the firebase post data config, in case you want to see it.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { moveIn, moveInLeft, fallIn } from '../router.animations';




interface utilfaq {

  erro: string;
  solucao: string;
  programa:string;
  tema:string;
  subtema:string;
  $key?: string;


}


@Component({
   selector: 'app-submissoesv2',
  templateUrl: './submissoesv2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./submissoesv2.component.css'],
  animations: [moveIn()],
  host: {'[@moveIn]': ''}
})

export class Submissoesv2Component{



  readonly errosPath = "erros";

  formutilfaq: utilfaq = {

    'erro' : '',
    'solucao' : '',
    'programa' : '',
    'tema' : ',',
    'subtema' : ',',

  };


  utilfaqsStream: FirebaseListObservable <utilfaq[]>;
  constructor(db:AngularFireDatabase){
    this.utilfaqsStream = db.list(this.errosPath);

  }

  onSubmit(): void{

    this.utilfaqsStream.push(this.formutilfaq);
    this.formutilfaq = {
    'erro' : '',
    'solucao' : '',
    'programa' : '',
    'tema' : '',
    'subtema' : ',',
  };



try {
      if (this.formutilfaq.$key) {
        this.utilfaqsStream.update(this.formutilfaq.$key, this.formutilfaq);
      } else {
        this.utilfaqsStream.push(this.utilfaqsStream);
      }

      this.formutilfaq = {
        'erro': '',
        'solucao': '',
        'programa' : '',
        'tema' :'',
        'subtema' : ',',
      };
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Form error:', e);
    }

}

edit(utilfaq: utilfaq): void {
    this.formutilfaq = utilfaq;
  }

  remove(utilfaqKey: string): void {
    this.utilfaqsStream.remove(utilfaqKey);
  }


}
```

My question is if I can send the data up to firebase with the images. I'll insert a camp on the form to upload images, if someone could help me here I would appreciate.